# Is there iPhone simulator on iPhone SDK 3.2?

Tags: iphone, ipad, simulator

I'm considering upgrade SDK 3.1.3 to 3.2 because 3.1.3 disappeared on Apple's website.
I used 3.2 SDK beta once, and any project launched *iPad* simulator only. (even iPhone project)

Is there *iPhone* simulator on SDK 3.2?
Or how to test iPhone app on SDK 3.2?

PS.
I have to check this before install because this is my main workstation, so I cannot put this into unstable or unusable state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can switch between iPad and iPhone under `Hardware -> Device`.

Answer (score 1):

In the build settings for a project, you can specify the deployment target to be iPhone OS 3.1.3 (or earlier). This will make the iPhone Simulator 3.1.3 (or earlier) available as a simulator (instead of only the iPhone Simulator 3.2, aka the iPad simulator)

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's documentation: "iPhone OS 3.2 does not support iPhone and iPod touch devices. It runs only on iPad." So you'll have to wait for iOS 4.