# How do I use the iPhone Simulator in 3.2 (not iPad Simulator)

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I'm fixing my app to be a universal binary.  Testing on the simulator seems to default to the iPad.  For small corrections like checking orientations and small UI updates, the only way I can find to get the iPhone version is to plug in my iPhone and build and run on device.

Loading the debugger takes valuable time, when running on simulator is so much faster for this kind of work.  Can I set the simulator to default to iPhone for this?  Setting it to 3.1.3 doesn't work because of the 3.2 code I have in the binary for the iPad.

EDIT:

The Hardware -> Device, and ->Version menu choices in the simulator quits my app.  When I relaunch, it goes back to the iPad.  The app is not installed in the simulator

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413948/setting-xcodes-target-to-iphone-not-ipad/2414107#2414107
This might help too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574147/is-there-iphone-simulator-on-iphone-sdk-3-2

Comment: It's not working.  It changes to the iPhone simulator, but the app quits.  When I relaunch, it goes back to the iPad.

Comment: I don't think you can run 3.2 code on the iPhone simulator.  It only supports 3.1.3.

Comment: It's my understanding that 3.2 is only for the iPad. Latest iPhone is 3.1.3

Comment: This sucks, because all of the iPad code throws errors when compiled for 3.1.3.  I have to test every little iPhone change on my actual device, which takes considerably longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the latest xcode, get it.

Set the project info to build for 3.2, but in the build drop down pick iPhone Simulator 4.0 and it will open in the iPhone simulator instead of the iPad simulator.

Answer (score 0):

That is the dilemma: if you want to use OS 4 on the iPhone, you have to use iPhone SDK 4, which comes with XCode 3.2.3.

Previously I used iphone_sdk_3.1.3_with_xcode_3.2.1__snow_leopard__10m2003a, where the simulator was fine, but now after I update the iPhone to OS 4 (which is by iTunes), I cannot use the SDK 3.1.3 any more, and the simulator 3.2 which comes with SDK 4 actually does not work for iPhone at all!

Even when you specify the "iPhone OS Deployment Target" to "OS 3.1.3", and an iPhone-frame shows up in the iPad simulator, many functions are not responding at all.

Does Apple have an official answer to this dilemma?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem myself.

First, install new version of xCode, which is xCode 4.

Then set project scheme to iphone simulator and run app in xCode several times.

And re-install xCode 3 and the problem will be gone away!